# xCode prints JSON response

Tags: json, xcode7

Has anyone printed JSON response in xCode for swift file and what was your experience reading it?  I find the new format extremely difficult to read. Here's an example of the JSON response I got back on my application:

```
Printing description of response:
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : blogs
    ▿ .1 : 1 elements
      ▿ [0] : 4 elements
        ▿ [0] : 2 elements
          - .0 : timeline
          ▿ .1 : 6 elements
            ▿ [0] : 2 elements
              - .0 : post_like
            ▿ [1] : 2 elements
              - .0 : follow
            ▿ [2] : 2 elements
              - .0 : achievement
            ▿ [3] : 2 elements
              - .0 : comment_like
            ▿ [4] : 2 elements
              - .0 : new_comment
            ▿ [5] : 2 elements
              - .0 : mentions
        ▿ [1] : 2 elements
          - .0 : email
          ▿ .1 : 6 elements
            ▿ [0] : 2 elements
              - .0 : post_like { ... }
            ▿ [1] : 2 elements
              - .0 : follow { ... }
            ▿ [2] : 2 elements
              - .0 : achievement { ... }
            ▿ [3] : 2 elements
              - .0 : comment_like { ... }
            ▿ [4] : 2 elements
              - .0 : new_comment { ... }
            ▿ [5] : 2 elements
              - .0 : mentions { ... }
        ▿ [2] : 2 elements
          - .0 : device
          ▿ .1 : 7 elements
            ▿ [0] : 2 elements
              - .0 : comment_like { ... }
            ▿ [1] : 2 elements
              - .0 : follow { ... }
            ▿ [2] : 2 elements
              - .0 : device_id
            ▿ [3] : 2 elements
              - .0 : post_like { ... }
            ▿ [4] : 2 elements
              - .0 : achievement { ... }
            ▿ [5] : 2 elements
              - .0 : new_comment { ... }
            ▿ [6] : 2 elements
              - .0 : mentions { ... }
        ▿ [3] : 2 elements
          - .0 : blog_id
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : other
    ▿ .1 : 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : email { ... }
        ▿ .1 : 2 elements
          ▿ [0] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_reply
          ▿ [1] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_like { ... }
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : timeline { ... }
        ▿ .1 : 2 elements
          ▿ [0] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_reply { ... }
          ▿ [1] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_like { ... }
      ▿ [2] : 2 elements
        - .0 : device { ... }
        ▿ .1 : 3 elements
          ▿ [0] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_reply { ... }
          ▿ [1] : 2 elements
            - .0 : device_id { ... }
          ▿ [2] : 2 elements
            - .0 : comment_like { ... }
  ▿ [2] : 2 elements
    - .0 : wpcom
    ▿ .1 : 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 2 elements
        - .0 : marketing
      ▿ [1] : 2 elements
        - .0 : research
      ▿ [2] : 2 elements
        - .0 : community
(lldb)
```

I prefer the old style with Object-C. Is there a way to revert back to that old format?

Comment: Please ask programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why it's shown the way it is. The reason is because the response is of  type. So if I cast the type into NSDictionary, then the output will have the structure we're used to.